# Salesforce Lightning - Link Formula Field

Tags: salesforce-lightning

I created the formula field below to show the link to a record. It works when I'm on different record, however, if I click the same link on a dashboard, it gives me the following error: URL No Longer Exists. The url adds "desktopDashboards." Can someone help me fix this issue?

HYPERLINK(LEFT($Api.Partner_Server_URL_260, FIND( '/lightning', $Api.Partner_Server_URL_260)) &  Id,  'Test')

Record link: 
https://company.lightning.force.com/lightning/r/Object__c/(id)/view

Dashboard link (with error message):
https://company.cs21.my.salesforce.com/**desktopDashboards**/(id)

Answer (score 0):

Hyperlinks can be either relative or absolute (more information on that under the tips for the [HYPERLINK documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=customize_functions_a_h.htm&type=5#HYPERLINK)). In your case it seems it is a relative URL, and so the behavior can change depending on which page you're viewing the hyperlink. One way to link to a record in Salesforce is simply prepending a slash ("/") to the ID. Here's an example:

```
HYPERLINK("/" & Id, "test")
```